# Getting permutations of weighted items that add up to a certain amount

Tags: python, permutation

I have element A weighing 1, and element B weighting 2. I need to find the possible permutations of A and B that add up to a certain amount.

For example, when the desired amount is 4, what I would like to get is:

```
[A, A, A, A] 
[B, B]  
[B, A, A]  
[A, B, A]  
[A, A, B]
```

What's the best way to do something like this? I initially tried to brute-force it by using itertools.permutations and checking sums manually (very inefficient, but I wasn't sure where else to go) but it wasn't possible for bigger numbers. I'd like to know a way to do it without importing itertools or another library, if possible?

Comment: This sounds like you are solving the Knapsack Problem. I suggest reading about existing solutions and see if they can be adopted to your problem.

Comment: Thank you! It looks like it's what I'm looking for. I figured a solution already existed but I couldn't search up the right words to find it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not *permutation* what you are looking for, but *combination*. Permutation is reshuffling the finite set of elements, without repetitions, while combination is every of `n` fields assuming one of `m` elements - which in python is denoted by `itertools.computations_with_replacement`. In terms of code:

```py
import itertools
from functools import reduce

elements = {"A": 1, "B": 2, "C": 1}
sum_restriction = lambda x: sum(elements[i] for i in x)==4
max_els = 4 // min(elements.values()) + 1

res = reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,[list(filter(sum_restriction, itertools.combinations_with_replacement(elements.keys(), i))) for i in range(max_els+1)])
```

For my example returns:

```py
>>> res
[('B', 'B'), ('A', 'A', 'B'), ('A', 'B', 'C'), ('B', 'C', 'C'), ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'A', 'A', 'C'), ('A', 'A', 'C', 'C'), ('A', 'C', 'C', 'C'), ('C', 'C', 'C', 'C')]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from itertools import permutations, chain


def get_permutations_count_to_n(item_dict, n, max_items=4):
    """ For a given dict with items as keys and weights as values, return a set of permutations that have a combined weight of N
    :param item_dict: dictionary with items as keys and their weight as value 
    :param n: integer that should be the combined weight of permutated items
    :param max_items: the maximum number of items that may occur in a permutation """
    item_list = list(items.keys()) * max_items
    combs = [list(permutations(item_list, i)) for i in range(1, max_items+1)]
    filtered_combs = [comb for comb in chain.from_iterable(combs) if sum(item_dict[x] for x in comb) == n]
    return set(filtered_combs)

items = {'A': 1, 'B': 2}
get_permutations_count_to_n(items, n=4)
```

```
>>> {('B', 'A', 'A'), ('B', 'B'), ('A', 'A', 'A', 'A'), ('A', 'A', 'B'), ('A', 'B', 'A')}
```